# Maskedtextbox money

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, maskedtextbox, money-format, krypton-toolkit

In C#, I use this `mask`:

```
$999,999.00
```

But I need to display the number as $123,123,12.

If I want to put 99.00, I need do 000099.00 I do not want to do it.

And if I use this:

```
$99.00
```

I cannot put a number as $100.00. How can I use the `mask` for numbers like:

```
$123,412,341,234.00 
and $99.00
and $9.00

maskedtextbox1.Mask="$999,999.00"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am concerned there is no way to mask entries with various lengths. It seems you will need to filter it manually.