# How to apply price format on a MaskedTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, maskedtextbox

Some example code on how to apply a price format on a MaskedTextBox, the mask at startup would be **$0.00** and when typing it begins by replacing the first zero from right to left, which is separating thousands, in winforms, VS 2017. As the image:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maskedtextbox money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960410/maskedtextbox-money)

Comment: Thanks, but what they answered is that it cannot be applied, I try to do it in C # since in Java it is possible

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with the `NumericUpDown` control, and a `Label`.

[image: NumbericUpDown]

[image: NumericUpDown max. value]

For this example, I set the follow properties of `NumericUpDown` to:

```
DecimalPlaces = 2
ThousandsSeparator = True
Maximum = 100000000
TextAlign = Right
```